# Asynchronous in Failure

Tags: scala

Why is the user's name not printed when I comment out the `println("testing")`?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Future3 extends App {
  val userFuture = Future(
  User("Me")
  )
  val userNameFuture: Future[String] = userFuture map {
    user => user.name
  }

  userNameFuture onSuccess {
    case userName => println(s"user's name =  $userName")
  }

  //  println("testing")
}

case class User(name: String)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900681/the-future-is-not-complete

Comment: If you remove `App` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

The `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` creates daemon threads. (see Scala source code `scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.DefaultThreadFactory`) These are threads the JVM will not wait for on exit (in your case, when the main routine stops). Thus, before the `userNameFuture` which runs as a daemon thread has finished, the main routine is already finished and does **not wait** for the future threads to finish.

To prevent this from happening, either use non-daemon thread, e.g. to create such an implicit `ExecutionContext`

```
implicit val ec = (scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
```

or use

```
Await.result( userNameFuture, Duration.Inf )
```

in the main routine.

Attention: If you use the latter approach with **both** `Await.result` **and** `onSuccess` callback, it still can happen, that the main routine exits first and no output of username will be made, as there is no order which of both happens first.

## Long answer

Have a look at the code

```
object F2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.util.Success

    val userFuture = Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println( "userFuture runs on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      User("Me")
    }

    val userNameFuture: Future[String] = userFuture map {
      user => {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println( "map runs on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName )
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        user.name
      }
    }

    val p = Promise[Boolean]()

    userNameFuture onSuccess {
      case userName => {
        println( "onSuccess runs on : " + Thread.currentThread().getName )
        println(s"user's name =  $userName")
        p.complete(Success(true))
      }
    }


    println( "main runs on: " + Thread.currentThread().getName )
    println( "main is waiting (for promise to complete) .... ")
    Await.result( p.future, Duration.Inf )
    println( "main got promise fulfilled")
    println( "main end ")

  }
}
```

whose output is

```
main runs on: run-main-b
main is waiting (for promise to complete) .... 
userFuture runs on: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
map runs on: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
onSuccess runs on : ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
user's name =  Me
main got promise fulfilled
main end
```

First, you can see, that both userFuture and it's map operation run on `ForkJoinPool` as daemon threads.

Second, main is run through first, printing "main is waiting for promise" and waits here (only for demenstration purposes) for the promise to be fulfilled. If main **wouldn't wait here** ( *try yourself, by commenting out the `Await`*) for the promise completion, the main routine would just print the other two lines and is done. As a result, the JVM would close (and you would never see output of `onComplete`)

## Trick (for debugging) via SBT

In general, if you are using SBT and invoke program execution via `run`, then you can still see the output of daemon threads, as the JVM is not terminated, if started from within SBT. 
So, if you start via SBT `run` you are soon back to the SBT prompt (because main routine has finished), but output of threads (`onComplete`) is visible in SBT.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that default `ExecutionContext` `global` executes your future block on daemon thread and main thread doesn't wait for daemons to complete. You can use `Thread.sleep(1000)`, `Await.result(userNameFuture, 1 second)` or another thread blocking operation in main thread to wait for some time so that your future's thread completes.

Another way is to run future on not-daemon thread:

import java.util.concurrent.Executors

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

object Future3 extends App {

  implicit val executor = ExecutionContext

    .fromExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())  //not-daemon threads


  val userFuture = Future(
    User("Me")
  )
  val userNameFuture: Future[String] = userFuture map {
    user => user.name
  }

  userNameFuture onSuccess {
    case userName => println(s"user's name =  $userName")
  }

}

case class User(name: String)
```